# correct style for element-wise operations on lists without numpy (python)

Tags: python, list, coding-style, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I would like to operate on lists element by element without using numpy, for example, i want `add([1,2,3], [2,3,4]) = [3,5,7]` and `mult([1,1,1],[9,9,9]) = [9,9,9]`, but i'm not sure which way of doing is it considered 'correct' style.

The two solutions i came up with were

```
def add(list1,list2):
    list3 = []
    for x in xrange(0,len(list1)):
        list3.append(list1[x]+list2[x])
    return list3

def mult(list1, list2):
    list3 = []
    for x in xrange(0,len(list1)):
        list3.append(list1[x]*list2[x])
    return list3

def div(list1, list2):
    list3 = []
    for x in xrange(0,len(list1)):
        list3.append(list1[x]/list2[x])
    return list3

def sub(list1, list2):
    list3 = []
    for x in xrange(0,len(list1)):
        list3.append(list1[x]-list2[x])
    return list3
```

where each operator is given a separate function

and

```
def add(a,b)
    return a+b
def mult(a,b)
    return a*b
def div(a,b)
    return a/b
def sub(a,b)
    return a-b
def elementwiseoperation(list1, list2, function):
    list3 = []
    for x in xrange(0,len(list1)):
        list3.append(function(list1[x],list2[x]))
    return list3
```

where all the basic functions are defined, and I have a separate function to use them on each element. I skimmed through PEP8, but didn't find anything directly relevant. Which way is better?

Comment: can't you use `map`? instead of `elementwiseoperation`. See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713321/element-wise-addition-of-2-lists-in-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The normal way to do this would be to use `map` or `itertools.imap`:

```
import operator
multiadd = lambda a,b: map(operator.add, a,b)
print multiadd([1,2,3], [2,3,4]) #=> [3, 5, 7]
```

Ideone: http://ideone.com/yRLHxW

`map` is a c-implemented version of your `elementwiseoperation`, with the advantage of having the standard name, working with any iterable type and being faster (on some versions; see @nathan's answer for some profiling).

Alternatively, you could use `partial` and `map` for a pleasingly pointfree style:

```
import operator
import functools

multiadd = functools.partial(map, operator.add)
print multiadd([1,2,3], [2,3,4]) #=> [3, 5, 7]
```

Ideone: http://ideone.com/BUhRCW

Anyway, you've taken the first steps in functional programming yourself. I suggest you read around the topic.

As a general matter of style, iterating by index using `range` is generally considered the wrong thing, if you want to visit every item. The usual way of doing this is simply to iterate the structure directly. Use `zip` or `itertools.izip` to iterate in parallel:

```
for x in l:
    print l

for a,b in zip(l,k):
    print a+b
```

And the usual way to iterate to create a list is not to use `append`, but a list comprehension:

```
[a+b for a,b in itertools.izip(l,k)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, and the tip about iterating over the list (i've always done it with range for some reason).

Comment: @user1858363 You're welcome. That's how you'd do it in C or Java; in python it's inefficient and less readable. It's only appropriate when you want to visit some subset of the items. Even then, I'd see if there's an `itertools` function which could help.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done with just using `map` and `operator` module:

```
>>> from operator import add,mul
>>> map(add, [1,2,3], [2,3,4])
[3, 5, 7]
>>> map(mul, [1,1,1],[9,9,9])
[9, 9, 9]
```

Comment: What's the point of interposing `func` here? It's literally just an alias for `map`.

Comment: @Marcin Correct you are, it would be better to remove the `func` because just `map` is fine

Comment: Also, I think you'll be interested in how `functools.partial` can make this into a reusable function without interposing a `lamdba`.

Comment: ;) Still, I hope it appeals to you. I'd actually forgotten it was built-in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use zip:

```
sum = [x+y for x,y in zip (list1, list2) ]
diff = [x-y for x,y in zip (list1, list2) ]
mult = [x*y for x,y in zip (list1, list2) ]
div = [x/y for x,y in zip (list1, list2) ]
```

Comment: Map would be cleaner and more efficient for this type of operation.

Answer (score 1):

## Performance Comparison

@Marcin said that `map` "would be cleaner and more efficient" than a list comprehension. I find that the list comprehension looks better, but that's a matter of taste. The efficiency claim I also found surprising, and that one we can test.

Here's a comparison for varying list sizes; code to generate the plot is below (note that this needs to be run in a Jupyter notebook or at least IPython. Also, it takes a bit of time to finish). `numpy` is not really up for comparison, because the OP needed to work with `list`s, but I included it because, if you're interested in performance, it's worth knowing what the alternative would be.

As you can see, there's no reason to favor one approach over the other based on efficiency concerns.

[image: performance comparison]

```
import numpy as np
import operator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

lc_mean = []  # list comprehension
lc_std = []
map_mean = []
map_std = []
np_mean = []
np_std = []

for n in range(1, 8):
    l1 = np.random.rand(10 ** n)
    l2 = np.random.rand(10 ** n)

    np_time = %timeit -o l1 + l2
    np_mean.append(np_time.average)
    np_std.append(np_time.stdev)

    l1 = l1.tolist()
    l2 = l2.tolist()

    lc_time = %timeit -o [x + y for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]
    lc_mean.append(lc_time.average)
    lc_std.append(lc_time.stdev)

    map_time = %timeit -o list(map(operator.add, l1, l2))
    map_mean.append(map_time.average)
    map_std.append(map_time.stdev)

list_sizes = [10 ** n for n in range(1, 8)]
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

np_mean = np.array(np_mean)
plt.plot(list_sizes, np_mean, label='np')
plt.fill_between(list_sizes, np_mean - np_std, np_mean + np_std, alpha=0.5)

lc_mean = np.array(lc_mean)
plt.plot(list_sizes, lc_mean, label='lc')
plt.fill_between(list_sizes, lc_mean - lc_std, lc_mean + lc_std, alpha=0.5)

map_mean = np.array(map_mean)
plt.plot(list_sizes, map_mean, label='map')
plt.fill_between(list_sizes, map_mean - map_std, map_mean + map_std, alpha=0.5)

plt.loglog()
plt.xlabel('List Size')
plt.ylabel('Time (s)')
plt.title('List Comprehension vs Map Add (vs numpy)')
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Great visualization. Performance will differ based on the version of python. Clearly that claim is outdated in whatever version you used. Can you post what you used? or even better run this over different versions ;)

Comment: Thanks! I'm using python 3.6.4; it is possible that, e.g., 2.7 might differ (probably most common when you wrote your comment), but I'll leave that as an exercise for any interested readers later (Python 2 has had it's time...). OS + CPU would certainly also make a difference in the timing, but I'd expect map + list comprehension to both be affected similarly.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import operator

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 3, 4]

sum = map(operator.add, a, b)
mul = map(operator.mul, a, b)
```

No, there is no sense in writing own functions in this case.
Just use `map` and `operator` as you won't implement anything better.
Any wrapper on `map` is just another stuff to be put on stack.
Any own implementation is slower than the builtin solution.