# python add objects from list into another list

Tags: python, list

I have not found an answer to my question: (maybe not the words to found it)
I have two lists, I would like to add each element (and keep the order) to another list.
For example:

```
A = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
B = ["123", "456", "789"]

result = ["abc123", "def456", "ghi789"]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result=[]
for i,j in zip(A,B):
        result.append(i+j)

also:
map(lambda x : x[0]+x[1],zip(A,B))
```

list comprehension we can acheive it in single line

```
[ x+y for x,y in zip(A,B)]
```

explanation:
above code is a list in which elements are x+y from the zip(A,B)

Comment: Thanks, I'm beginner so I understand the first one. I choose it !

Answer (score 2):

```
result = [ a + b for a, b in zip(A, B) ]
```

Even better (using a generator instead of an intermediate list):

```
from itertools import izip
result = [ a + b for a, b in izip(A,B) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = [ str(a)+str(b) for a, b in zip(A, B) ]
```

Thanks to `str()` usage, you can have lists of any objects, not only strings, and your result will be list of strings.

Comment: why converting string to again string

Comment: Thanks to that you can use A = [1, 2, 3] and it won't fail. I've explained, that it will allow any type of lists elements.

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

map (lambda t: t[0]+t[1], zip(A,B))

Comment: No need for a *lambda*.  Use the operator module instead:  ``map(add, A, B)``.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way would be using [`operator.__add__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) and [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).

```
from operator import __add__

A = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
B = ["123", "456", "789"]

print map(__add__, A, B)
```

Comment: why adding a module? I have already so much in my program

Comment: `from operator import __add__` will only import the built-in function `__add__`, not the whole module. Also, this approach [has the advantage that is faster than others](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18713344/2670792), except for a numPy solution.