# How to read columns from a file and add each column in separate lists in python 3.4

Tags: python

I need dynamic code:

if the file data looks like below, then how can I add each column of it in 3 list separately in python 3.4.1?

```
0 4 5

1 0 0

1 56 96
```

I tried and read the data from file and stored it in a list like: `scores = [['0','4', '5'],['1','0','0], ['1', '56','96']]`. but now I don't know how write the code to put each first letter of this array to 3 separate lists or arrays. like: `list1 = [0, 1,1]`, `list2 = [4,0,56]` and `list3 = [5,0,96]`

thanks

Comment: This question has already been answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713321/element-wise-addition-of-2-lists-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you have a list of the rows, and you want a list of the columns. This is called *transposing* and can be written very concisely in Python like this:

```
columns = zip(*scores)
```

After doing this, `columns[0]` will contain the first column, `columns[1]` the second column, and so on. The columns will be tuples. If you really need lists you can apply the `list` function to the result:

```
columns = map(list, zip(*scores))
```

This dark-magic-looking syntax first uses the `*` operator which [unpacks a list of arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). Here this means that `zip(*scores)` is equivalent to:

```
zip(['0','4', '5'], ['1','0','0'], ['1', '56','96'])
```

Note how each element of the `scores` list is now a different argument of the `zip` function. Then we use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function.

Comment: I have tried zip but it says "zip object at 0x10291fb08> and whle trying map it says"map object at 0x102a1b668>.

Comment: Oh, this is because you are using Python 3.x and not Python 2.x. In this case try: `columns = list(zip(*scores))`