# Sum Parts of Multiple Lists

Tags: python, list, sum

I'm sure there is a good way to accomplish what i want without looping over lists and creating new objects. Here is what I have

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

What I am looking to do is take each set of lists and sum each placeholder so that the output is

```
[3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Thoughts?

Comment: So, is an [element-wise sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713321/element-wise-addition-of-2-lists-in-python) what you're looking for?

Comment: The `map` method doesn't return a `list` anymore in python3. You would have to call `list(map(...))` to get a list back again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use zip function and list comprehension

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5]
[sum(t) for t in zip(a,b)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5])
a+b
>>> array([3, 5, 7, 9])
```