# download file, argument1 does not support iteration python

Tags: python, arrays, sum, zip

I am trying to add 2 arrays together, and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713321/element-wise-addition-of-2-lists-in-python), problem is, it gives me error for some reason and I don't know how to fix this.
code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import sys

# cd Desktop/python Exercises/pythonEx05
# python main.py mnist_train_1vs7vs8.csv mnist_validation_1vs7vs8.csv    
mnist_test_1vs7vs8.csv


# Loads the dataset
data = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1],  delimiter = ',')
# Split the data to matrix X and vector Y
X = data[:, 1:]
Y = data[:, 0]

wMatrix=(len(X[0]),3)
np.zeros(wMatrix)

for i in range(0,len(Y)):
        if(yGag!=Y[i]):  #Y[i] is the right y, to fix later
            wMatrix[i]= [a + c for a, c in 
            zip(wMatrix[i], X[i])]
```

The last line gives me error

```
  argument1 does not support iteration
```

..HELP? its just adding 2 arrays, that's all

Comment: `wMatrix` is a tuple `wMatrix=(len(X[0]),3)` with length 2  so `wMatrix[i]` will either return `len(X[0])` or `3` both are `int` not `list`.

Comment: ok, so how do I change it to list?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. But you don't change it to list. It not being list means whatever you are trying to do your logic is wrong and you need to rethink it?

Comment: mm as i said, i just want to add 2 arrays.. if i could do that on last i will define it in a different way. question is how i could do this

Comment: If `wMatrix[i]` and `X[i]` both are lists then you are doing it right.