# How do I add every number from a list to a number?

Tags: python

These are my lists. How do I add every number from `list1` to every number in `list2`?

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
outcomelist = [7,8,9,10,11,8,9,11,12,9,10,11,12,13,10,11,12,13,14,1,12,13,14,15]
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the stackoverflow community. This question has already been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-to-append-list-to-second-list-concatenate-lists

Comment: So what's your question? Can you update your question with the code that you have tried so far or add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to the question?

Comment: I don't know whether you expect `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`, or `55`, or `[7, 9, 11, 13, 15]`...

Comment: What's your expected output?...

Comment: @ssuperczynski: I'm fairly sure the OP wants this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713321/element-wise-addition-of-2-lists-in-python

Comment: "Every number to every number" could also mean permute all the numbers, i.e. add the sum of the first list to every element in the second list. But I concur with @FLHerne and vote to close as probably a duplicate of that question.

Comment: The final list should look like this:[7,8,9,10,11,8,9,11,12,9,10,11,12,13,10,11,12,13,14,1,12,13,14,15] ?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3
this:[7,8,9,10,11,8,9,11,12,9,10,11,12,13,10,11,12,13,14,1,12,13,14,15]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) build-in function and [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

```
[x + y for x, y in zip([1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10])]

>>> [7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
```

Or don't do `zipping` if you want sum up all to all:

```
[x + y for x in [1,2,3,4,5] for y in [6,7,8,9,10]]

>>> [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: This was helpful but if if wanted the final list look like this 
[7,8,9,10,11,8,9,11,12,9,10,11,12,13,10,11,12,13,14,1,12,13,14,15] ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a new list, you can do:

```
list3 = [x + y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

If you what you want is updating list2, you canalso use enumerate to access the index and update the list:

```
for idx, tuple in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
    list2[idx] = tuple[1] + tuple[0]
```

Comment: This was helpful but if if wanted the final list look like this [7,8,9,10,11,8,9,11,12,9,10,11,12,13,10,11,12,13,14,1,12,13,14,15] ?

Answer (score 0):

python3

```
add=lambda x,y:x+y
list(map(add,list1,list2))#[7, 9, 11, 13, 15]

import operator
list(map(operator.add,list1,list2))#[7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
```

list comperhension:

```
[x+y for x,y in zip(list1,list2)]#[7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
[sum([x,y]) for x,y in zip(list1,list2)]#[7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.product` to make all the possible pairs:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> list2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
>>> [x + y for (x,y) in itertools.product(list1, list2)]
>>> resultlist
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

You can extend this to multiple lists:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3]
>>> list2 = [4,5,6]
>>> list3 = [7,8,9]
>>> [x + y + z for (x, y, z) in itertools.product(list1, list2, list3)]
```

Or even variable number of lists:

```
>>> [sum(items) for items in itertools.products(*list_of_lists)]
```