# how to perform addition of items in two different lists in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

list1 = [ 1, 2, 3]

list2 = [4, 5, 6]

I want to perform addition on these lists in this way: 1+4, 2+5, 3+6.. and so on.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713321/element-wise-addition-of-2-lists possible duplicate of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element-wise addition of 2 lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713321/element-wise-addition-of-2-lists)

Comment: The question is about doing that type of calculation in Robot Framework. To me native RF script does not equal Python so these two duplicate references are incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Robot Framework there aren't many calculation keyword options in the [BuiltIn Library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html). There are certainly no native ones and we often resort to using [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) to evaluate a python expression. This python expression is further explained in the already mentioned  [Element-wise addition of 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713321/element-wise-addition-of-2-lists). Combining both the the below code:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Map Lamda Calc
    ${list1}    Create List    ${1}    ${2}    ${3} 
    ${list2}    Create List    ${1}    ${2}    ${3}
    ${CalcList}    Evaluate    map(lambda x, y: x + y, $list1, $list2)
    Log To Console    \n${CalcList}
```

Which will then result in the following console response:

```
==============================================================================
Test                                                                          
==============================================================================
Test.calcLists                                                                
==============================================================================
Map Lamda Calc                                                        
[2, 4, 6]
| PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test.calcLists                                                        | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
============================================================================
```

In the code the ${1} construct is used to ensure that the value stored is indeed an [robot framework integer](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variables). Otherwise a string is provided and then a concatenation is performed.

Answer (score 0):

A robotframework native solution, using the [for in-zip](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-in-zip-loop) construct - it itterates over two lists, up to the length of the smaller one:

```
${list a}=  Create List  1  5  3  8 
${list b}=  Create List  2  4  7
${result}=  Create List
:FOR  ${a}  ${b}    IN ZIP  ${list a}  ${list b}
\  ${sum}=  Evaluate  int($a) + int($b)
\  Append To List  ${result}  ${sum}
```

When ran, the value of `${result}` will be `[3, 9, 10]` - as `${list b}` is with just 3 members.
Inside the evaluate all source lists members are casted to int - so if any is not a number-like object, the case/keyword will fail on that step.