# Element wise, variable combination of lists in python

Tags: python, list, elementwise-operations

Preface: [Element-wise addition of 2 lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713321/element-wise-addition-of-2-lists)

I want to write to code to have the following behavior:

```
[ 1, 1, ["Alpha"]]
+
[ 2, 2, ["Beta"] ]
||       ||     ||
\/       \/     \/
[3, 3, ["Alpha", "Beta"]]
```

in python. Is this possible without very messy comprehensions and mapping?

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate since the answers given (and the pythonic answers) are duplicates of the linked question. The short answer is `yes`, you can avoid maps/comprehension using loops.

Comment: I will also add, since no one has added this answer, that you can use reduce and a custom lambda for aggregating any number of weird data types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, though I'd think twice before calling list comprehensions messy. Pass `operator.__add__` to `map` along with the two lists:

```
import operator
list(map(operator.__add__, l1, l2))
# [3, 3, ['Alpha', 'Beta']]
```

Comment: You can just use `operator.add`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was trying to be a special snowflake.

Comment: operator.__add__ answers my question better. I've accepted this question because of this.

Comment: @Erich I believe add and __ add __ do the same thing :)

Comment: For this purpose yes. But if you define `__add__` in a class then the behavior  will not be the same as add. Which is more of what I was asking but it's a bit after the fact.

Comment: @Erich Fair enough. Will rollback my answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
[a + b for a, b in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Comment: Indeed. I'd be interested to know if the OP thinks it's a "messy comprehension".

Comment: I believe in an older version of python that this did not work for custom defined classes, or that it at least didn't work for my use case because I tried this and it failed. I forget that use case now unfortunately, but this does now work, at least for my machine.

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses list comprehensions, although they are, imo, far from messy. Also, it is pretty readable and doesn't require a library

```
a = [1, 1, ["ALPHA"]]
b = [2, 2, ["BETA"]]
c = [a[i]+b[i] for i in range(len(a))]
print(c)
```