# How to sum two rows in a list?

Tags: python, list

I want to sum the 3rd and 4th rows in my list?
I am looking for the easiest way to do that?
I know it seems so easy, but I cannot find the similar examples, as I am thinking I don't use the right keywords!

```
[0.001, 0.017000000000000001, 4.0, 75.0]
[5352984.0, 23194715.0, 8.0, 150.0]
[2370914.0, 11533745.0, 21.0, 396.0]
[0.39500000000000002, 0.68100000000000005, 68.0, 1296.0]
[0.46400000000000002, 0.69099999999999995, 69.0, 1307.0]
[0.0, 0.001, 12.0, 226.0]
[0.0, 0.001, 10.0, 194.0]
[0.055, 0.22600000000000001, 7.0, 136.0]
[0.055, 0.109, 10.0, 181.0]
[0.001, 0.037999999999999999, 29.0, 556.0]
[0.0030000000000000001, 0.14099999999999999, 46.0, 873.0]
[0.0, 1.0, 15.0, 287.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 108.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 29.0, 556.0]
[0.0, 0.024, 46.0, 873.0]
[7086684.0, 68448914.0, 3.0, 53.0]
```

Comment: This is an improper example and shows no effort.  If you cant code it, explain with some sample data as to what is going on and what you want to occur.

Comment: If you update the question with the expected output and your current code that tries to implement this feature, we can try to answer your question.

Comment: What is the value of `row`? Isn't it as simple as `row[0] + row[1]`?

Comment: I just modified the question and the items in the rows I have

Comment: If it's always those same rows, you could do `[x + y for x,y in zip(a[2], a[3])]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element-wise addition of 2 lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713321/element-wise-addition-of-2-lists)

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that your list is like this:

```py
this_list = [[0.001, 0.017000000000000001, 4.0, 75.0],
             [5352984.0, 23194715.0, 8.0, 150.0],
             [2370914.0, 11533745.0, 21.0, 396.0],
             [0.39500000000000002, 0.68100000000000005, 68.0, 1296.0],
             [0.46400000000000002, 0.69099999999999995, 69.0, 1307.0],
             [0.0, 0.001, 12.0, 226.0],
             [0.0, 0.001, 10.0, 194.0],
             [0.055, 0.22600000000000001, 7.0, 136.0],
             [0.055, 0.109, 10.0, 181.0],
             [0.001, 0.037999999999999999, 29.0, 556.0],
             [0.0030000000000000001, 0.14099999999999999, 46.0, 873.0],
             [0.0, 1.0, 15.0, 287.0],
             [0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 108.0],
             [0.0, 0.0, 29.0, 556.0],
             [0.0, 0.024, 46.0, 873.0],
             [7086684.0, 68448914.0, 3.0, 53.0]]
```

and your "3rd row" is this:

```py
[ 4.,  8., 21., 68., 69., 12., 10.,  7., 10., 29., 46., 15.,  6., 29., 46.,  3.]
```

Then you can simply:

```py
import numpy as np
np_list = np.array(this_list)
# sum in a new row
new_row = np.sum([np_list[:,2], np_list[:,3]], axis=0)

# sum each elements of the 3rd and 4rd rows separetadly
row3, row4 = np.sum([np_list[:,2], np_list[:,3]], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A function can be made for this.

```
def RowSum (gridlist,row):
        sumcount=0
        for sublist in gridlist: # iterates through every sublist
                   sumcount+=sublist[row-1]
        return sumcount
```

For your work of summation of row 3 and 4:

```
rsum= RowSum(gridlist,3)+RowSum(gridlist,4)
print(rsum)
```

Note that this function is designed keeping in mind that the row number starts from 1 and not from 0.

Thank You :)