# Merging two lists with same number of elements and adding them sequentially

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've got something like:

```
list1 = [1, 3, None]
list2 = [2, 5, None]
```

And I'm looking to get something like:

```
merged_list = [12, 35, None]
```

P.S. Both lists will always have the same length and could have a None value as an element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element-wise addition of 2 lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713321/element-wise-addition-of-2-lists)

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: i think you should explain why you want to do this

Comment: @incapaz @jonsharpe @mayeul-sgc Hi, sorry for maybe not explaining that well the output, but essentially is merging the elements of both in the subsequential order (i.e. if the element of first list is `'lala'`, and from second list is `'land'`, the first element of the `merged_list` would be `'lalaland'`, just that in this case is numerical values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip together the two lists and process each respective pair of elements.

```
[10 * a + b if a and b else None for a, b in zip(x, y)]
```

This list comprehension will combine a and b if neither are None. Otherwise, it will just put None.

Edit: If you just want to merge whatever values, do the same thing, but make sure you cast to a string so any value will work:

```
[str(a) + str(b) if a and b else None for a, b in zip(x, y)]
```

Note, it doesn't do the merge in place, but returns a new array with the combined values

Comment: or [10*a + b if a and b else None for a,b in zip(list1, list2)]

Comment: @mauve Good idea, I changed it. That's a better solution since they want the elements to be ints instead. No casts needed

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but sorry i didnt explain well. But essentially is merging the elements of both in the subsequential order (i.e. if the element of first list is `'lala'`, and from second list is `'land'`, the first element of the `merged_list` would be `'lalaland'`, just that in this case is numerical values.

Comment: @LucasMengual Changed it to work with strings or ints. The logic is the same, just how you handle the combining of the two values.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to combine strings here. Something like

```
merged_list = []
for(i,j in zip(list1, list2):
  if(element is not None):
    merged_list.append(float(str(i) + str(j))
  else:
    merged_list.append(None)
```

Code not tested!