# Create numpy array based on multiple conditions on two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given two arrays as such

```
a = np.array([0,1,0,1,0,0])
b = np.array([0,0,1,1,1,0])
```

I want to create a numpy array based on conditions as

```
output = np.zeros(len(arr1))

for i in range(0, len(arr1)):
    if a[i] == 0 and b[i] == 0:
        output[i] = 0
    elif a[i] == 1 and b[i] == 0:
        output[i] = 1
    elif a[i] == 0 and b[i] == 1:
        output[i] = 2
    elif a[i] == 1 and b[i] == 1:
        output[i] = 3


expected_output = np.array([0,1,2,3])
```

what is the fastest way of creating such array?

Comment: edited. I hope it's clearer now. I have tried using np.where, but it doesn't seem to support different outputs from different conditions.

Comment: Err... Isn't this just counting upwards? This isn't very clear still.

Comment: `c = a + 2*b` should do it

Comment: edited with a simpler example

Comment: @hpaulj I wonder if `c  = a | b << 2` is faster?

Comment: Looking at the older examples you gave, I'm curious, what is this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The others gave examples how to do this in pure python. If you want to do this with arrays with 100.000 elements, you should use numpy:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: vector1 = np.array([0,1,0,1,0,1])
In [3]: vector2 = np.array([0,0,1,1,2,2])
```

Doing the element-wise addition is now as trivial as

```
In [4]: sum_vector = vector1 + vector2 * 2
In [5]: print(sum_vector) # python3.x kaugh...
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

just like in Matlab ;-)

U may see also : [Element-wise addition of 2 lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713321/element-wise-addition-of-2-lists)

Answer (score 0):

As answer above sugested, this is the fast\easiest way:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0,1,0,1,0,0])
b = np.array([0,0,1,1,1,0])

a + 2*b
```

Answer (score 0):

In the most generalized sense, you can use boolean arrays to assign values to indices matching whatever criteria that you want.

This:

```
for i in range(0, len(arr1)):
    if a[i] == 0 and b[i] == 0:
        output[i] = 0
    elif a[i] == 1 and b[i] == 0:
        output[i] = 1
    elif a[i] == 0 and b[i] == 1:
        output[i] = 2
    elif a[i] == 1 and b[i] == 1:
        output[i] = 3
```

Is equivalent to:

```
output[a == 0 & b == 0] = 0
output[a == 1 & b == 0] = 1
output[a == 0 & b == 1] = 2
output[a == 1 & b == 1] = 3
```

or:

```
a0 = a == 0
b0 = b == 0
a1 = a == 1
b1 = b == 1
output[a0 & b0] = 0
output[a1 & b0] = 1
output[a0 & b1] = 2
output[a1 & b1] = 3
```