# Python Dataframe add two columns containing lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, pandas-apply

I have a dataframe of two columns, each containing list as elements. I want to perform rowwise element additon of two lists. My below solution is inspired from this answer [Element-wise addition of 2 lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713321/element-wise-addition-of-2-lists)

My code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[1,2,3],[10,20]],'B':[[4,5,6],[40,50]]})

           A          B
0  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]
1   [10, 20]   [40, 50]

df['C'] = df[['A','B']].apply(lambda x: list(map(add,x[0],x[1])))
df['C'] = 
    A   B
0  11  44
1  22  55
```

Expected answer:

```
df['C'] = 
   C
0 [5,7,9]
1 [50,70]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to apply the function row-wise, you just need `axis=1`:

```py
from operator import add
df['C'] = df[['A','B']].apply(lambda x: list(map(add,x[0],x[1])), axis=1)
```

or

```py
df['C'] = df[['A','B']].apply(lambda x: [i+j for i,j in zip(*x)], axis=1)
```

An alternative option is to `explode` the lists; `sum`; then `groupby.agg` to get the lists back in:

```py
df['C'] = df.explode(['A','B']).sum(axis=1).astype(int).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Output:

```py
           A          B          C
0  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]  [5, 7, 9]
1   [10, 20]   [40, 50]   [50, 70]
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I am happy to have come this close to the actual answer. Also, I found an alternative answer as `df[['A','B']].apply(lambda x: [sum(x) for x in zip(x[0],x[1])],axis=1)`