# Is there any way to add two lists together without a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this code:

```
list1 = [8, 2, 3]
list2 = [7, 1, 6]
for element in list1:
    list1[element] += list2[element]
```

Something to note is that list1 and list2 are always the same size.

I tried this:

```
list1[0] += list2[0]
list1[1] += list2[1]
list1[2] += list2[2]
```

except that doesn't scale with list size.

Comment: The first one won't work as `element` is not an index. Why don't you like loops?

Comment: There are a number of answers from https://stackoverflow.com/q/18713321/2745495, some of which don't use a plain loop. Are they not sufficient? Please [edit] to clearly describe your constraint with not using loops.

Answer (score -2):

> ## Using python only

```
list1 = [8, 2, 3]
list2 = [7, 1, 6]
sum_list = list(map(sum,zip(list1, list2)))
```

print(sum_list)

```
output: [15,3,9]
```

> ## Using Numpy

```
list1 = [8, 2, 3]
list2 = [7, 1, 6]
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array(list1)
array2 = np.array(list2)
sum_array = np.sum([array1, array2], axis=0)
list_sum = sum_array.tolist()
print(list_sum)

output: [15,3,9]
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions half an hour after they've been closed as duplicate of multiple questions which already have plenty of answers.

Comment: Bringing numpy into this is shooting with cannons at sparrows.

Comment: Just edited and checked the output on a python interpretor

Comment: Found this question on the lists of unanswered questions

Comment: Your answer was already proposed in one of the duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56208488/15032126.

Comment: Thanks @IgnatiusReilly for pointing that out. I edited my answer to correct the namespace error